# I would like to open/close a menu with one button, I want to use only Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&#9776;</a>
```

Comment: where is `myNav` element?

Comment: You mean a toggle menu?

Comment: html code for the menu. you should add the html code for the menu that you want to hide and show

Comment: I can't seem to be able to edit my question. I got the code from w3schools but they do not have a one button method. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_overlay2

Answer (score 0):

You have to explain it better but I think I understand what you want.

Just use display block.

Something like this :

```
function openNav() {
var menu = document.getElementById("myNav").style.display;

If (menu == "block") {
menu="none";
}else{
menu="block";
}}

// Open and close div 
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</a>
```

I'm not sure if the syntax is right because I'm writing this from my phone.

But I think it's works.

Lets me know.

Comment: If or else? That is what I'm looking for, single button. Sorry will be more specific next time.

Answer (score 0):

it should be toggle function

```js
    function toggleNav(){
        var myNav = document.getElementById("myNav");
        if(!myNav) return;
        myNav.style.display = myNav.style.display.toLowerCase() != 'none'? 'none' : 'block';
    }
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="toggleNav()">&#9776;</a>

<div id="myNav" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #ff0000; display:none;"></div>
```

Comment: How do I stop it from opening automatically?

Comment: set `display: none` 

=> `<div id="myNav" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #ff0000; display:none;"></div>`

Comment: You're just hiding it until you click it twice

Comment: `function toggleNav() {
        var myNav = document.getElementById('myNav');
        if (myNav.style.display === 'block') {
         myNav.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
         myNav.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }`   Fixed it myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="toggleNav()">&#9776;</div>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
<div class="overlay-content">
<a href="#">About</a>
<a href="#">Services</a>
<a href="#">Clients</a>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>

<style>
html, body{ 
margin: 0;
}
.overlay {
height: 0%;
width: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
overflow-y: hidden;
}

.overlay-content {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 50px;
}

.overlay a {
padding: 8px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 36px;
color: #818181;
display: block;
transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
color: #f1f1f1;
}

.closebtn{
position: absolute;
float: right;
right: 15px;
top: 10px;
font-size: 30px;
cursor: default;
color: #eee
}
</style>

<script>
function toggleNav(){
    var myNav = document.getElementById("myNav");
    if(!myNav) return;
    myNav.style.display = myNav.style.display.toLowerCase() != 'none'? 'none' : 'block';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Managed to get it right, Thanks all :) This is not how I wrote it in text editor.